# Receiving payments from Android Market

Tags: android, payment, google-play

So I've recently been selling away on the Android Market. As of yet, nothing has appeared in my bank but after reading [this](https://checkout.google.com/support/sell/bin/answer.py?hl=en-uk&answer=25400), it appears that payments are supposed to appear in your bank after so many days after being charged from the users account.

I was just wondering, is this every single sale? Separately appearing in your statement? Or does Google build it up and then deposit it, say at the end of the month?

Comment: This probably belongs on programmers.stackexchange.com or the like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found a better solution. If you go to your Google Checkouts settings page and then click financials you can set how often you'd like your payouts!

Answer (score 1):

If you are over the limit, it deposits every day what you earned from the day before. According to my experience, the limit varies from $10 to $20. But, I don't know the actual limit. On the other hand, don't forget that you will receive your first payment after 60 days as said in the link.

Comment: Does the limit change then? I can't find out what it is!

Comment: Thanks. This might be annoying for my company but I guess there isn't much I can do!

Answer (score 0):

I got my payment after the first month and get it monthly and it is on monthly basis on 2. of the month.

I'm not able to change it but that could depend on the country you are in (I'm in CH)

Comment: In the UK there are options to change it as I mentioned in the answer above. Some countries may be restricted, I don't know as I'm not in them!